# Literature on VARs

Tags: time-series, references, vector-autoregression

I'm looking for literature where vector autoregressions are comprehensively described. I'd like to know which consequences some assumptions lead to. For example, which properties of estimates follow from imposing stationarity conditions on series (or deviating from these conditions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically any time series textbook will give you a definition of VAR process , conditions for its existence and the properties of the estimates. I can recommend J. D. Hamilton's [Time Series Analysis](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html) for general exposition and H. Lutkepohl's [New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540401728) for more detailed coverage.